# Use of lock keywork c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I am working on a C# coding exercise with this code:

```
class Program
{
    static object sync = new object();

    static void SafeRun()
    {
         lock (sync)
         {
              Thread.Sleep(1000);
         }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         lock (sync)
         {
              SafeRun();
         }

         Console.Write("Safe");
     }
   }
}
```

What will be printed?

1. Nothing, a deadlock occurs.
2. It does not compile.
3. "Safe" will print.

I thought that deadlock will occur, but when I run the code "Safe" is printed.

So, can you explain to me why 3 is correct and why 1 is not correct?

Thank you!

Comment: There is only one thread running in this program, the main thread, the sync resource is being accessed twice but by the same thread so there won't be a deadlock situation.

Comment: Run the program and see what it will print: that is your homework, isn't it? Btw it will print "Safe"

Answer (score 3):

For `deadlock` to occur you need at least 2 Threads which want to access resources locked between them.

**Example:**

You have 2 running `Thread` and 2 `List<T>`.

`Thread A` is **locked** the `List A`. The `Thread A` want to take value from `List B`

`Thread B` is **locked** the `List B`. The `Thread B` want to take value from `List A`

Now both `Threads` will try to get resources which are locked between them.

Answer (score 2):

Your program is *single thread* one, so it's *thread safe* by default (to have a *deadlock*, *race condition* ect. you have to have at least *two* threads). Any `lock`s are in fact do nothing - there're no other threads to lock (that's why all `lock` can be dropped).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    lock (sync) // does nothing (no other treads to lock)
    {
        SafeRun(); // execution
    }

    Console.Write("Safe"); // printing out
}

static void SafeRun()
{
    lock (sync)  // does nothing (no other treads to lock)
    {
           Thread.Sleep(1000); // 1 second pause
    }
}
```

You program just

- start
- call `SafeRun()`
- wait 1 second
- print out `"Safe"`

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `lock` is used to restrict a certain resource from being accessed by other threads. Since your application isn't using multiple threads, it's impossible for a deadlock to occur.